# Slow file transfer to USB thumbdrive

Tags: raspbian, usb, performance, peripherals

Currently my files are transferring at a speed of 10 kilobytes/s or less to a thumbdrive that is Fat32 formatted. I have a pretty stock Raspian install, and I've done an rpi-update.   I am using a powered USB hub as well.

I've run a test with this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/usb0/test.dat bs=1M count=10
```

and it's output:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 102.429 s, 10.2 kB/s
```

Any ideas? This seems even slower than usual.  Are there any cool tools like `ethtool` to debugging the usb connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some more investigating (different disk formats, etc) and I've nailed it down to how I was mounting the fat partition.  I was using a old program `usbmount` which included a `sync` option.  This option was cool, because it meant that the data was written to the disk immediately, instead of cached and synced later (thus you could didn't have to worry about "safely removing" the thumbdrive).  But it wasn't because the CPU utilization reached 100% for the entire file transfer, and I had those slow speeds.  Removing the sync option from `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`, and running sync() manually right after I `cp`ied something was the solution.  I figured this out thanks to this forum post: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=412068#p412068 and systematically trying to remove the various mount options in the config.