# USB Drive I/O is Slow

Tags: usb, pi-2

I have a USB thumb drive plugged into the Pi. It's a USB3 drive but I know that the Pi is only USB2, so I'm expecting speeds to be in the average 35-40MB/s range.

However, what I'm getting is only around 15MB/s, which I determined by using `hdparm -tT`. My sdcard gives me `20MB/s`. Is there any way to increase the I/O performance of the USB drive?

Comment: Have you tried using different usb drives?

Comment: A quick google showed me that usb 2.0 has this kind of speed by default. Also know that everything connected to the USB or build in ethernet shares the same bus on the RPI source: http://usbspeed.nirsoft.net/

Comment: My device (ADATA S102PRO 64gb) is listed on that link and it shows that it should have a speed of about 27MB/s read. I only have the drive and a usb keyboard plugged in to the pi so that majority of the bandwidth should be available for the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it helps:  [Slow file transfer to USB thumbdrive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9457/slow-file-transfer-to-usb-thumbdrive)

(Sorry, I can't create a comment due to my low reputation, so have to provide an answer!)